# SVD with matlab, numpy and pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, pytorch

Matlab

```
A=[-0.67645626,  0.63071378, -0.27856928;
       -0.02497551,  0.42396278,  2.22727768;
       -0.43153722,  1.20107944,  0.39737373;
       -0.878973  , -1.20829399,  0.40960471]
[x,y,v]=svds(A)
```

numpy

```
u_np, s_np, vh_np = np.linalg.svd(a, full_matrices=False, compute_uv=True)
```

The result from matlab for right singular vector(v) is

```
-0.0807 -0.1227 0.9892
0.3219  -0.9424 -0.0906
0.9433  0.3111  0.1155
```

The result from numpy for right singular vector(vh_np)T is

```
array([[ 0.08067148, -0.12268262,  0.98916181],
       [-0.32185978, -0.94243885, -0.09063832],
       [-0.94334426,  0.31105947,  0.11551454]])
```

Can you please explain, where is there a difference in sign. The result woulld be same if the matrix is square matrix.

Consistent result from numpy (Pytorch preferable) and matlab. I cannot figure out which one is the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `numpy.linalg.svd()`'s [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html), the rows of `vh_np` (likewise, the columns of `vh_np.T`) are right-singular vectors, which are eigenvectors of A^H @ A .

The sign of an eigenvector is arbitrary (see for example [this discussion on *Cross Validated*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154716/)), i.e. if `v` is an eigenvector, so is `-v`. Note that this is not a property of SVD, but of eigenvectors in general. Consistent with this property, both Matlab and Numpy provide the same correct solutions in your example, as they only differ in the sign of the first vector (ignoring numerical imprecision or round-off error).

If you want to resolve the ambiguous sign, you need to do that yourself; for example, by choosing it such that the largest vector component is always positive (which might be ambiguous as well, e.g. if multiple vector components have the same absolute value).

**Update**: As you also asked for a PyTorch solution: You will achieve the same result using `torch.linalg.svd()`:

```py
import torch

A = [[-0.67645626,  0.63071378, -0.27856928],
     [-0.02497551,  0.42396278,  2.22727768],
     [-0.43153722,  1.20107944,  0.39737373],
     [-0.878973  , -1.20829399,  0.40960471]]

u_torch, s_torch, vh_torch = torch.linalg.svd(torch.tensor(A))
print(vh_torch.T)
# >>> tensor([[-0.0807, -0.1227,  0.9892],
#             [ 0.3219, -0.9424, -0.0906],
#             [ 0.9433,  0.3111,  0.1155]])
```

This solution, again, has the same ambiguity regarding the signs of the vectors, which you will need to resolve yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab `svd` returns the right singular vectors as the columns of the matrix `v`.

NumPy `linalg.svd` returns the transpose of the right singular vectors as the rows of the matrix `vh`.

You can transpose the matrix `vh_np` returned by `NumPy` to obtain the the same matrix of right singular vectors and compare the results from MATLAB and NumPy directly:

```
v_np = vh_np.T
```

Comment: The result from numpy for right singular vector(vh_np)T , I have mentioned that I guess. The result  above is obtained by doing the transpose.